# placeholder not working in jquery mobile with select

Tags: jquery-mobile, placeholder

http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2FJ/

As you can see in the example above, data-placeholder="true" is not working.

Can anyone suggest workaround please?

Also [the official document](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html) does not show the placeholder.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="subject"><em>* </em> Subject: </label>
<select name="subject" id="subject" class="required" data-placeholder="true"  data-native-menu="false">
<option value=""  >Select subject</option>
<option value="Art">Art</option>
<option value="Band">Band</option>
<option value="Choir">Choir</option>
<option value="Design">Design</option>
<option value="Drama">Drama</option>
...
...
</select><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated jquery Mobile to 1.2.0 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the attribute `data-native-menu="false"` which is causing jQM to behave this way

You Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2FJ/1/

Without the attribute:

- http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2FJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the `data-native-menu="false"` attribute so you get a pop-up selection box, simply make the first option selected from you js on pageload:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subject option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```